# Low-rank SVD reconstruction and linear projection of the data

Tags: pca, svd

**Short version:** 
I  wonder if the singular value decomposition (SVD) low-rank approximation  $X = U_q\Sigma_q V^T_q$ is a projection onto $V_q$ or $V_q^T$?

**My understanding of the answer:** The basic idea is that $BA^T = (A^TB)^T$ when we set the data of $X$ in rows and we want our projections to result in rows again.

The **projection** is given by $\langle v,x\rangle v$ since $v$ is a unit vector:

[image]

so everything makes sense. (I was confused - I thought is was given by $Vx$)

---

I read [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf), that the solution to $$\min_{\mu,V_q,\lambda}\Big(\sum_i \|x_i- \mu - V_q\lambda\|_2^2    \Big),$$  meaning the reconstruction (approximation) of data points by an affine hyper-plane of rank $q$ ($V_q$ is orthogonal matrix), is given by $\mu=\bar{x}, \lambda_i = V_q^T(x_i-\bar{x}) $
and $V_q$ is the first $q$ columns of $V$ in the SVD decomposition $$X = U\Sigma V^T.$$

But as far as I understand (also in [here](https://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/abdi-awPCA2010.pdf)) the principle components are the columns of $V^T$(!) so if we want to find the projection of $X$ on the rank-$q$ approximation we will left-multiply by $V$ (which outputs a vector in $Span(V^T)$) and indeed $$XV = U\Sigma V^TV = U\Sigma$$

which are the PC scores (on the rows); for new data we will just left-multiply by $V$ to get the projection.

Also, in the same book the authors showed that the rank-2 reconstruction is actually $ U\Sigma$ :

[image]

So, is the hyperplane on the left picture above is the span of $V_2$ or $V_2^T$? and if it's the latter, how does it settle with fact that the approx. hyper-plane is $V_2$ according to minimization problem?

Comment: GuyL, You needed not necesarily to delete your initial commented question; it could be edited instead.

Comment: `V` is the orthonormal basis which axes (columns) are principal components. Points are projected onto them.

Comment: @ttnphns - because of your comments on the the first question I understood what I really wanted to ask - Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion is probably due to how the data matrix is organized.

In *The Elements of Statistical Learning* (and also in the Abdi & Williams paper you linked to), data matrix $\mathbf X$ has data points in rows and variables in columns; so one data vector is *a row*. Whereas a single data vector $\mathbf x$ is usually understood to be *a column* vector. So one has to be carefully watching the algebra: if you want to project the data onto an axis $\mathbf v$, you need to write $\mathbf X \mathbf v$, but $\mathbf v^\top \mathbf x$.

Now, if $\mathbf X$ is centered and you do singular value decomposition (SVD) $$\mathbf X = \mathbf {USV}^\top,$$ then COLUMNS of $\mathbf V$ are principal axes (also called principal directions). The first column is the first axis, the second column is the second axis, etc. To project the data onto the first two principal axes, we write $\mathbf X \mathbf V_2$, where $\mathbf V_2$ are the first two columns of $\mathbf V$. The hyperplane spanned by the first two principal axes is spanned by the first two columns of $\mathbf V$. There is no contradiction.

Comment: I have a similar misunderstanding. Suppose I treat observations as column vectors and rows as features; i.e. work with $Y = X^T = V S U^T$. Now to project data into the principle component space we project onto $col(Y)$, and since $V$ is a basis for this space, we have a projection matrix $V (V^T V)^{-1} V^T = V V^T$. So the projection of a data point $z = x^T$ as a column vector into this space is $V V^T z$, which gives us a column vector again. If we transpose to get the projected data point back in rows-as-data orientation we get $x V V^T$, which somehow has an extra $V^T$!?