# Project Matrix Data onto PCA Space

Tags: pca, linear-algebra, projection

Given a matrix A with dimension m by n which is a matrix of m samples and n features. Also SVD of Matrix A = U * Sigma * V^T, How to project matrix A onto its k principal components with only U and Sigma?

From my understanding to project our data onto its k principal components, we need to multiply A by V thus, AV = U * Sigma * V^T * V = U * Sigma. Is this correct?

Comment: Indeed, please refer to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/172300/271601